# How to set up a Jenkins pipeline to use a secrets.properties file that isn't committed to GitHub

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a Springboot/Maven based application that uses a `secrets.properties` file to store tokens. The file contains a key/value pair as `IEX_CLOUD_TOKEN=MY_TOKEN`.

After running my Jenkins pipeline, I get the error shown below. It makes sense that it's failing because `secrets.properties` is not in GitHub. How can I set up the pipeline to use my token when it's needed by the application?

I set up a credential in Jenkins and set it's `Kind` to `Secret file`. I then added a `withCredentials` script to my `Jenkinsfile`. However, I still get the error message below.

Error Message

```
context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.StockportfolioApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [secrets.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        pollSCM '* * * * *' // 5 stars means poll the scm every minute
    }
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.6.3'
    }
    options {
        skipStagesAfterUnstable()
    }
    environment {
        IexCloudApiKey=credentials('IEXCloud')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'IEXCloud', variable: 'FILE')]) {

                    sh '''
                    cat $FILE > secrets.properties
                    mvn test
                    rm secrets.properties
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The other question which is coming up. Why do you need the secrets? For tests?

Comment: The ‘$IexCloudApiKey’ is a temporary file.  Instead of echo you can use cat command. However, the output will be masked. Your application can definitely read that file as intended. If you need the file in different location, just use cp command, example’cp $IexCloudApiKey myDestination’

Comment: @khmarbaise I am making calls to an external API and am using it as part of an integration test. This may not be a good approach and would be happy to learn if that's the case.

Comment: If it's an integration test it should run in the integration test phase (integration-test) usually handled by maven-failsafe-plugin ...

Comment: @khmarbaise how do I tell `mvn test` to only run unit tests instead of all test classes?

Comment: @RamKamath I have updated the original question to show what I am testing now. This however still fails with a file not found exception. As as I can tell, I am creating a `secrets.properties` file and writing the contents of `FILE` to it. So the file should exist.

Comment: @RamKamath I've realized that Jenkins has its own directory where it copies files into and I needed to create a `secrets.properties` file in that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First several comments about your pipeline.

The pipeline duplicates a lot of steps because you [know the life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in Maven? If you call `mvn compile` and afterwards `mvn test` you will repeat several steps including `compile` even worse using `mvn package` also repets several steps...including `test` and `compile` so first simplify it to `mvn package`.

Furthermore you should use a [setup for credentials to be done outside](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) the workspace like this:

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'secret', variable: 'FILE')]) {
    dir('subdir') {
      sh 'use $FILE'
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: I run into an error that says the use command is not found. More specifically, it provides the message below. Why is this? /Users/mlewis/IntelliJProjects/CS673/StockPortfolio/src/main/resources@tmp/durable-5e187b1e/script.sh: line 1: use: command not found